# Passing data from one view controller to another view controller(floating pannel) in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controllers

1. home view controller
2. floating pannel view controller

i am using this [library](https://github.com/SCENEE/FloatingPanel#show-or-show-detail-segues-from-floatingpanelcontrollers-content-view-controller) as the floating pannel

using calandar to get selected date in home view controller and pass it to the floating pannel.

[image: view controllers shows in here]

like shows in here

this is the function i used to get the selected date from calendar

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
    log.success("date has been selected")/
       
    day = formatter.string(from: date) }
```

is there any way i can send the date from home view controller to floating pannel.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's very dependent on what you want to achieve by sending the date to the floating panel. you have some option.

1. Make an delegate protocol for the home view controller (something like this):

protocol HomeDelegateProtocol: AnyObject {

```
func set(date: Date)
```

}

2. Make the floating panel class extend the HomeDelegateProtocol
3. Set the floating panel object be his delegate
4. Call the delegate function